# Simple multiplication calculator not retaining decimal value

Tags: javascript, html, converters, calculator, multiplication

This is a simple multiplication calculator which on typing automatically adds  comma to separate groups of thousands. However it doesn't accept decimal value for example 1,778.**23**. Copy pasting it directly into the field works but can't type it. Any solution would be much appreciated.

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = updateValue('box1');
  var myBox2 = updateValue('box2');
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  adTextRes('result', myResult)
}

function updateValue(nameOf) {
  var inputNo = document.getElementById(nameOf).value;
  var no = createNo(inputNo);
  adTextRes(nameOf, no);
  return no;
}

function adTextRes(nameOf, no) {
  var asText = String(no).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById(nameOf).value = asText;
}

function createNo(textin) {
  return Number(textin.replace(/,/g, ""));
}
```

```html
<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Box 1</th>
    <th>Box 2</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="box2" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="result" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, in `createNo`:

```
return Number(textin.replace(/,/g, ""));
```

A trailing period will just get discarded when converted to a `Number`. There's no need for such a casting in the first place, though - just leave it off, and it'll work as expected:

```
function createNo(textin) {
  return textin.replace(/,/g, "");
}
```

To prevent multiple decimal points from being entered, you can use another `replace` in the same function:

```
.replace(/(\.\d*)\./, '$1')
```

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = updateValue('box1');
  var myBox2 = updateValue('box2');
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  adTextRes('result', myResult)
}

function updateValue(nameOf) {
  var inputNo = document.getElementById(nameOf).value;
  var no = createNo(inputNo);
  adTextRes(nameOf, no);
  return no;
}

function adTextRes(nameOf, no) {
  var asText = String(no).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById(nameOf).value = asText;
}

function createNo(textin) {
  return textin
    .replace(/,/g, "")
    .replace(/(\.\d*)\./, '$1')
}
```

```html
<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Box 1</th>
    <th>Box 2</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="box2" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="result" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There still might be some room for improvement, this code accepts multiple decimal points ...

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm looking for.